# Display only relevant hunks of a diff/patch based on a regexp

Tags: git, diff, patch

`git log -G<regex> -p` is a wonderful tool to search a codebase's history for changes that match the specified pattern. However, it can be overwhelming to locate the relevant hunk in the diff/patch output in a sea of mostly irrelevant hunks.

It’s of course possible to search the output of `git log` for the original string/regex, but that does little to reduce the visual noise and distraction of many unrelated changes.

Reading up on `git log`, I see there's the `--pickaxe-all`, which is the exact opposite of what I want: it broadens the output (to the entire changeset), whereas I want to limit it (to the specific hunk).

**Essentially, I’m looking for a way to "intelligently" parse the diff/patch into individual hunks and then execute a search against each hunk (targeting just the changed lines), discard the hunks that don’t match, and output the ones that do.**

**Does a tool such as I describe exist? Is there a better approach to get the matched/affected hunks?**

Some initial research I've done...

- If it were possible to `grep` the diff/patch output and make the context option values dynamic—say, via regexps instead of line counts—that might suffice. But `grep` isn't exactly built that way (nor am I necessarily requesting that feature).
- I found the [patchutils](https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils) suite, which initially sounded like it might suit my needs. But after reading its `man` pages, the tools doesn't appear to handle matching hunks based on regexps. (They can accept a list of hunks, though...)
- I finally came across [splitpatch.rb](https://github.com/jaalto/splitpatch), which seems to handle the parsing of the patch well, but it would need to be significantly augmented to handle reading patches via `stdin`, matching desired hunks, and then outputting the hunks.

Comment: Not exacly what you asked but try git log -Gfoo | less +/foo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35434714/5305907 is described a way to do what you are looking for. effectively:

`git diff -U1 | grepdiff 'console' --output-matching=hunk`

It shows only the hunks that match with the given string "console".

Comment: thanks. `grepdiff` is basically what i want; i must've missed its hunk-matching option! *however*... the git commit info is stripped by `grepdiff`, so once you locate the relevant hunk, you must divine the commit sha from the object/blob sha in the diff header—quite an expensive operation. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/223890/2284440) it'd be something like `git find-object SHA --reverse | head -1 | cut -c 1-7 | { read sha ; git log -1 $sha; }`

Comment: also note there's a [golang version of `grepdiff`](https://github.com/rsc/grepdiff) which is more barebones in terms of accepted arguments. note that when the matched hunk is the last hunk in a diff, it incorrectly includes the git commit header of the following commit—something that completely confused me until i realized what's going on!

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the answer above by @nagu, and the other linked answers, I was able to get `git log -G` to only show the relevant hunks.

1. First create a script somewhere in your $PATH with this content:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   # pickaxe-diff : external diff driver for Git.
   #                To be used with the pickaxe options (git [log|show|diff[.*] [-S|-G])
   #                to only show hunks containing the searched string/regex.

   path=$1
   old_file=$2
   old_hex=$3
   old_mode=$4
   new_file=$5
   new_hex=$6
   new_mode=$7

   filtered_diff=$(diff -u -p $old_file $new_file | \
                   grepdiff "$GREPDIFF_REGEX" --output-matching=hunk | \
                   grep -v -e '+++ ' -e '--- ')

   a_path="a/$path"
   b_path="b/$path"

   echo "diff --git $a_path $b_path"
   echo "index $old_hex..$new_hex $old_mode"
   echo "--- $a_path"
   echo "+++ $b_path"
   echo "$filtered_diff"
   ```
2. Call `git log -G` and tell Git to use the `pickaxe-diff` script as an external diff driver:

   ```bsh
   export GREPDIFF_REGEX=<string>; 
   GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=pickaxe-diff git log -p --ext-diff -G $GREPDIFF_REGEX
   ```

   This will use the pickaxe-diff script just to generate the diffs, so the rest of the `git log` output (commit hash, message, etc) will be untouched.

*Caveat*
The way that the Git pickaxe work is that it limits the output to the *files* whose hunks change the given string/regex. This means that if another hunk in these files also contain the search string/regex, but does not change it, it will still be displayed with the above script. This is a limitation of grepdiff. There is an open pull request at the patchutils project to add an `--only-matching` flag to grepdiff, which would provide the needed functionality to correctly filter out these hunks.

---

I did a write-up of my solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/phil-blain/2a1cf81a0030001d33158e44a35ceda6).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but one way to grep through hunks is the interactive-add mode. This requires you to check out the commit after the patch you're interested in

```
git checkout COMMIT_ID
```

then go back one more step in the VCS, but not in the working directory

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

(At this point, the difference between the index and the working directory will correspond to the patch you're interested in.)

You can now execute `git add -p`. This will launch an interactive session which has a `/` option, that allows you to locate hunks in whichs some line matches a regex. Particularly useful if you actually want to further process those patches (like, preparing a partial cherry-pick).

Unfortunately, at least right now the `/` command in `add -p` only works within a single file, so you may need to skip several unrelevant files.